# Print generic array to console

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I print a generic array to console? This works for simple integer arrays but not for generic ones.

```
class procedure Print(const A: TArray<Integer>; const Name: String);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Write('Array ' + Name +' : ');
  Write('[');
  for I := 0 to High(A) do
  if I <> High(A) then
  begin
    WriteLn(A[I]);
    Write(', ');
  end
  else
  Write(A[I]);
  Write(']');
  WriteLn('');
end;
```

Comment: Please can you clarify the question. Your code works just fine. That is once you fix the syntax errors

Comment: I assume he or she wants to do this for any kind of T in TArray<T>, IOW, (s)he wants a `class procedure Print<T>(const A: TArray<T>; const Name:string);`. I assume (s)he doesn't know how to do the `Write(A[I]);` part if `A[I]` is generic.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Exactly! Strings, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Write` and `Writeln` procedures cannot be called with generic arguments. Thus the obvious conclusion is that you need to convert the generic value to a string before calling `Write` and `Writeln`.

This can be achieved using `TValue` by taking advantage of the following capabilities:

1. The generic `TValue.From<T>` method that makes a new `TValue` instance.
2. The `TValue.ToString` method that converts most common types to string.

So, I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Rtti;

type
  TMyClass = class
    class procedure Write<T>(const arr: array of T; const Name: string); static;
  end;

class procedure TMyClass.Write<T>(
  const arr: array of T; const Name: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  System.Write('Array ' + Name +' : [');
  for I := 0 to high(arr) do begin
    System.Write(TValue.From(arr[i]).ToString);
    if I <> high(arr) then begin
      System.Write(', ');
    end;
  end;
  System.Writeln(']');
end;

begin
  TMyClass.Write<Integer>([1,2,3,4], 'integer');
  TMyClass.Write<Double>([42.666, 123.4], 'floating point');
  TMyClass.Write<string>(['foo', 'bar'], 'string');
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
Array integer : [1, 2, 3, 4]
Array floating point : [42.666, 123.4]
Array string : [foo, bar]
```

---

As an aside it really annoys me that I have to create a class to hold these methods. I don't understand why the language designers took that decision.

Comment: Heck, I totally forgot about `TValue.ToString`.

Comment: FWIW, `TStringHelper` has a method `Join(Separator, Values)`, which could make the loop a little simpler. It does require you to generate an `array of string` first, though.

Comment: @David: it is slightly annoying that this can't be done in a global function or procedure (i.e. a non-method), indeed. But I guess this was done, then, to be compatible with Delphi for .NET.

Comment: @rudy thanks for the edit. I never got past the string helper's appalling quality in its original form. It is galling that all of this hits the heap so hard.

Comment: I found quite a few errors in TStringHelper when I was writing and testing my TAnsiString replacement for AnsiString, and reported them. These have all been solved, AFAICT.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, is there a constraint in generics for simple types? Can't find any docs about it, but often I find this to be a valuable restriction when using generics.

Comment: @rudy I submitted lots of QC reports at the time. I'm sure they are fixed now. It is apalling that they did not appear to have done any proper testing of such a fundamental type. Worrying.

Comment: @LURD there is no such constraint. You have interface, record (which means value type), class and then class/intf is a constraints.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Worrying indeed. Delphi is too expensive to have these stupid bugs. QC center is getting bigger and bigger each day.

Comment: @LURD: as David said: there is no constraint for simple types (yet). FWIW, I just noticed that the `<Integer>`, `<Double>` and `<string>` qualifications can be omitted. A simple `TMyClass.Write([...]);` will do here (at least for the types used here).

Comment: There is a slight slight problem with this answer. It will stop working when you add `System.SysUtils` to the uses.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Incompatible types - `System.Rtti.TValue.T` with `TMyClass.T`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes this happens if you make a generic class  `TMyClass<T> = class`

Comment: That's a problem with your code rather than a problem with my answer. Fix it with `TValue.From<T>` instead of `TValue.From`.